# X/G exists as variety, so does X/H for H<G?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a field, $G$ a linear algebraic group acting on $X$, such that $X/G$ exists as a scheme and $X\rightarrow X/G$ is a $G$ torsor locally trivial in etale topology.

However today I don't feel like modding out the whole group, so let $H\subset G$ be a closed subgroup. Is it true, that $X\rightarrow X/H$ exists as a scheme and is a $H$ torsor locally trivial in etale topology?